# Join Two XPath Queries

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xquery

Hye there I am new to XML Read I want to Join these Two Queries!

```
 /ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE[@class='Activity']
```

and

```
 /ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description' and @type='STRING']
```

i tried:

```
  /ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE[@class='Activity'] | /ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description' and @type='STRING']
```

But the Problem is that it gives me wrong output using my code as:

```
NodeList nodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile(expression).evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODESET);

ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();

int k;
for (k = 0; k < nodeList.getLength(); k++) {

 String txt=nodeList.item(k).getTextContent();
 txt=txt.replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("#","").replace(":", "").replace("•", "").replace("\n", " ")
       .replace("\u0092", " ").replace("'", "").replace("•", " ").replace("-", " ").replace("’", " ").replace("\n", " ");


text.add(txt);


}
```

So how can i join the above two Queries

Comment: Define "wrong" - what XML are you working with, what output do you _want_, what do you actually _get_ and how do the two differ?

Comment: it gives me  NODE x6.5cm y10.5cm index7  EXPR expr(cond (avalf ("%o", "Responsible role")... this kind of output

Comment: Please _edit_ the question to include an example of the XML you're querying, the output you _want_ and the output you're currently getting.  We can't read your mind to know what counts as "right" or "wrong", and we can't suggest how to correct it if we don't know what input you're starting from.

Answer (score 1):

With `/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE[@class='Activity']` you are selecting an `INSTANCE` with a criteria; with `/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description' and @type='STRING']` you are selecting an `ATTRIBUTE` with a critera.

Change to:

```
/ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE[@class='Activity'] | /ADOXML/MODELS/MODEL/INSTANCE/ATTRIBUTE[@name='Description' and @type='STRING']/..
```

and it will now both select for  `INSTANCE` that meet different criteria. The `/..` goes back up a level to select a parent in the XPATH rather than the terminal element.

Comment: When you run it with each half of the XPATH (either side of the `|`) do you get the right output?

Comment: What does your raw XML look like? You might also want to check to see what `String txt=nodeList.item(k).getTextContent();` is getting prior to your processing of it with `.replace`.